# Maximum rise on outdoor steps

Tags: stairs, landscaping

I am working with a contractor to build stone/cinder block steps on a 30 to 35 degree slope.  He is thinking to put 10 inch risers. Although that is above the level I am seeing in my cursory search (up to 7 1/2 inches?) it honestly does not *seem* unreasonable. Are there objective concerns that would speak against using these higher 10 inch risers?

Comment: Residential code requires risers to be no more that 7.75 inches. Since this is outdoors, I guess the question would be, are these considered stairs? Other relevant questions, does this work require/is it permitted?

Comment: Regardless of specific code, 10 inches is _really_ tall. Any folks approaching senior status will not appreciate stairs that steep at all. Even if code doesn't apply, don't go more than about 8-1/2".

Comment: What do you consider "objective" concerns outside legality? Everything else is subjective.

Comment: @isherwood Well - i guess your comment about ten inches being "really" tall would qualify - since it reflects that most folks don't want to "reach" so much each time.   I personally prefer about 12 inches - but then I like doing 2 stairs at a time ;)

Comment: The older you get the more  you will curse the day you allowed the contractor to install steps with a 10" rise. Me, I am retired so I prefer 6" to 6.5" risers.

Comment: That's still a subjective assessment, WCP. I wish you well on your project, but I'm voting to close as a matter of opinion and local code.

Comment: "Even if code doesn't apply" - I'm pretty sure code applies on the West Coast. If you're going to close this it's because it's googleable. But I can't resit upvoting "stairs are stairs". **7.75 inches**

Comment: @GlenYates - even if w/e it is doesn't require a permit, it still has to be done to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation it seems that the following regulations do fairly uniformly apply both for interior and exterior stairs. Here is the code for Washington State where I reside [Washington State Stairwell Building Codes](https://legalbeagle.com/6864794-washington-state-stairwell-building-codes.html)

> Individual risers must have a height no greater than 7 3/4 inches and a depth of at least 10 inches.

Apparently "stairs are stairs" and to be properly considered as such they should follow the regulations whether inside or out.

We have changed direction to using those standards for our external staircase. We are working on how to handle railings.

Answer (score 1):

The code defines stairway as exterior or interior. An exterior stairway is one that is open on at least one side. (See Section IBC 1002.1)

A step shall not be less than 4” nor more than 8” high. (See IBC R311.5.3.4)

A handrail is required on at least one side when there are more than 3 steps. (See IBC R311.5.6)